# Changes made in one spreadsheet must get reflected in another spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet "shared" where it consists of all the bill of materials. I want to keep another spreadsheet "master" such that only owner can access that. Any data inserted in the shared spreadsheet should get reflected in master spreadsheet, but if we edit shared spreadsheet it should not get reflected in master spreadsheet.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on what you mean by "changes", but you could put `=Master!A1` in cell A1 of the slave sheet, then drag the bottom right corner all the way down, then drag the bottom right corner of that selection all the way across. So cell D8 will have `=Master!D8`, and so on.

Comment: thanks for your interest.I could have used importrange or importdata formula but if I edit shared spreadsheet it is getting changed in master as well which i don't want.I want to take only newly added data in shared to master not the editted ones.Hope you got my point now.

Comment: Ok, I see. I'm afraid I don't know of a way to do this. I'm tempted to say it can't be done, although someone might correct me.

Comment: Hope we get a answer for this.This will be useful if we are duplicating a spreadsheet and using that as a master one.Otherwise no purpose in duplicating a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Google Spreadsheets does have a scripting capability. It also has a public gallery script.

[image http://img593.imageshack.us/img593/5410/screenshot20110720at736.png](http://img593.imageshack.us/img593/5410/screenshot20110720at736.png)

One of the public scripts is `edit to another spreadsheet`

```
edit to another spreadsheet
update in another spreadsheet the changes in the current one
ticcaje (at) gmail.com
```

[image http://img97.imageshack.us/img97/240/picture1nns.png](http://img97.imageshack.us/img97/240/picture1nns.png)

unfortunately it has not been updated in some time, and after looking at the code I don't think it was ever actually completed, as there is a dialog message and then a return statement.

[image http://img718.imageshack.us/img718/5264/pictureja.png](http://img718.imageshack.us/img718/5264/pictureja.png)

I think this could be a really useful script and so I've done a little editing with it, but actually there are no comments in it, and I don't have the time to get it working 100% right now, but I wanted to post it here in hopes that somebody could actually pick it up and run with it.

```
function onEdit(){


  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AntUWac3dtkUac3dtnhTjMwac3dtVjBiac3dtOXcac3dt'); //put in your spreadsheet key here


  var sourcesSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  var targetSheet = targetSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];



  var currentSourceCellIndex = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRow();    //ActiveCell().getValues();
  var selectedCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSelection().getA1Notation();
  var targetRowsCount = targetSheet.getLastRow();          
  var targetColumns = sourcesSheet.getLastColumn();


  var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(1, 1, targetRowsCount, targetColumns);
  var targetSources = targetRange.getValues();        

  var sourceRows = sourcesSheet.getLastRow();
  var sourceColumns = sourcesSheet.getLastColumn();
  var sourcesRange = sourcesSheet.getRange(1, 1, sourceRows, sourceColumns);
  var sources = sourcesRange.getValues();
  var compareName = sources[currentSourceCellIndex-1][0];  



  return;



  //Browser.msgBox("currentSourceCell: "+sources[currentSourceCellIndex-1][0]);return;  // ActiveCell()
  //Browser.msgBox("currentSourceCell: "+targetRowsCount);
 // return;                       
  for (var i = 1; i < targetRowsCount; ++i) {
    if (targetSources[i-1][0] == compareName){

      targetSheet.deleteRow(i);
      break;    
    }
  }      

//    var sourceRows = sourcesSheet.getLastRow();
//    var sourceColumns = sourcesSheet.getLastColumn();

//    var sourcesRange = sourcesSheet.getRange(1, 1, sourceRows, sourceColumns);
//    var sources = sourcesRange.getValues();

    //if ((sources[sourceRows-1][0] == "")||(sources[sourceRows-1][1] == "") ||(sources[sourceRows-1][2] == "") || (sources[sourceRows-1][3] == "") || (sources[sourceRows-1][4] == "") || (sources[sourceRows-1][5] == "")) 
    //return;  

    //currentSourceCell = sourceSheet.getActiveCell();

    rowToInsert = targetSheet.getLastRow();      
    targetSheet.insertRowAfter(rowToInsert);
    var insertRange = targetSheet.getRange(rowToInsert + 1, 1, 1, targetSheet.getLastColumn());


    var kolonnen = [];
    var tbText   = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < 16; ++i) {
      kolonnen.push(i);
      tbText.push(sources[sourceRows-1][i-1]);
    }

    //Browser.msgBox("source is: "+tbText);return;                      
    for (j = 0; j < kolonnen.length; j++) {
       var zellRange = targetSheet.getRange(rowToInsert+1, kolonnen[j], 1, 1);
         zellRange.setValue(tbText[j]);
    }


}
```

The original code can be accessed by editing the script, but if you want it I'll just go ahead and post it here, too:

```
function onEdito() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var menuEntries = [ {
        name: "go",
        functionName: "insertRow"
    }
    //    ,
    //    {
    //        name: "Build Journal",
    //        functionName: "collectJournal"
    //    }
    ];
    ss.addMenu("pastePlus", menuEntries);
}

function onEdit(){

  var sourceSpreadsheetName = Browser.inputBox("source spreadsheet");  
  //var sourceSpreadsheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();

  var files = DocsList.getFilesByType("spreadsheet");
  //var files = SpreadsheetApp;

  Browser.msgBox("currentSourceCell: " +files);
  //var sourceSpreadsheet;
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
    var filename = files[i].getName();
    if (filename == sourceSpreadsheetName) {
      var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(files[i].getId());
      var sheets = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheets();
      var sourcesSheet = sheets[1];
      break;
    }
  }

  var targetSpreadsheetName = "Probando Script"; //DocsList.getFilesByType("spreadsheet");     

    //var targetSpreadsheet;
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
        var filename = files[i].getName();
        if (filename == targetSpreadsheetName) {
            var targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(files[i].getId());
            var sheets = targetSpreadsheet.getSheets();
            var targetSheet = sheets[1];
            break;
        }
    }

  var currentSourceCellIndex = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRow();    //ActiveCell().getValues();      
  var selectedCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSelection().getA1Notation();
  var targetRowsCount = targetSheet.getLastRow();          
  var targetColumns = sourcesSheet.getLastColumn();


  var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(1, 1, targetRowsCount, targetColumns);
  var targetSources = targetRange.getValues();        

  var sourceRows = sourcesSheet.getLastRow();
  var sourceColumns = sourcesSheet.getLastColumn();
  var sourcesRange = sourcesSheet.getRange(1, 1, sourceRows, sourceColumns);
  var sources = sourcesRange.getValues();
  var compareName = sources[currentSourceCellIndex-1][0];  

  //Browser.msgBox("currentSourceCell: "+sources[currentSourceCellIndex-1][0]);return;                       
  Browser.msgBox("currentSourceCell: "+targetRowsCount);return;                       
  for (var i = 1; i < targetRowsCount; ++i) {
    if (targetSources[i-1][0] == compareName){

      targetSheet.deleteRow(i);
      break;    
    }
  }      

    var sourceRows = sourcesSheet.getLastRow();
    var sourceColumns = sourcesSheet.getLastColumn();

    var sourcesRange = sourcesSheet.getRange(1, 1, sourceRows, sourceColumns);
    var sources = sourcesRange.getValues();

    //if ((sources[sourceRows-1][0] == "")||(sources[sourceRows-1][1] == "") ||(sources[sourceRows-1][2] == "") || (sources[sourceRows-1][3] == "") || (sources[sourceRows-1][4] == "") || (sources[sourceRows-1][5] == "")) 
    //return;  

    //currentSourceCell = sourceSheet.getActiveCell();

    rowToInsert = targetSheet.getLastRow();      
    targetSheet.insertRowAfter(rowToInsert);
    var insertRange = targetSheet.getRange(rowToInsert + 1, 1, 1, targetSheet.getLastColumn());


    var kolonnen = [];
    var tbText   = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < 16; ++i) {
      kolonnen.push(i);
      tbText.push(sources[sourceRows-1][i-1]);
    }

    //Browser.msgBox("source is: "+tbText);return;                      
    for (j = 0; j < kolonnen.length; j++) {
       var zellRange = targetSheet.getRange(rowToInsert+1, kolonnen[j], 1, 1);
         zellRange.setValue(tbText[j]);
    }


}
```